# Arduino ide rendering issue

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, arduino-ide

I have trouble with Arduino IDE on the new Ubuntu 12.04 armhf.
Just wondering whether anyone else had similar problem and knows how to resolve it. Here is a photo of the screen. I'm running the Ubuntu on UDOO dev board and I have attached it to a motorola lapdock. I didn't have this problem with armel ubuntu.

http://i57.tinypic.com/fkbrq0.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is the Lubuntu's default compositor. I installed xcompmgr following the instructions provided in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53745/compositing-in-lubuntu) and now the Arduino IDE works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a related rendering issue with the Arduino IDE on a Windows machine with an NVIDIA graphics card. The toolbar were rendered all weird, with the tab parts erased and icons drawn at the wrong place instead. The menus would also get screwed up too, with some items disappearing and others being repeated. See image below.

I finally solved it by temporarily disabling some hardware acceleration on the card (turning off DirectDraw acceleration). Annoying, but solves the problem while working with Arduino. I wonder if your problem had to do with hardware acceleration too.

[image]